# Hardware code(s) from "sensors" command

Tags: linux, terminal, hardware, temperature

When running the *sensors* command in the terminal, the output contains what appears to be some sort of unique identifier for each piece of hardware listed. This is the output, as you can see below, for all the components listed. Is there a way to map these listed identifiers to their respective component; i.e. TB0T = CPU Temp?

The machine in question is a MacBook Pro.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `x` will be which object, such as which CPU or which GPU if you have more than one. If you only have one, it will be `0`.

TA = Ambient temperatures
TAxP = ambient temp

TC = CPU temperatures
TCxD = CPU die temp
TCxH = CPU Heatsink temp
TCxP = CPU proximity

TN = Northbrige temperatures
TNxP = Northbridge position temp

TG = GPU temperatures
TGxH = GPU heatsink
TGxF = GPU fan
TGxP = GPU position

TB = battery temperatures

Ts0P = sensor near palm rest

This is from an older spec sheet:

```
Bit   Hex      Dec    Key   Description
---  ------   -----   ----  ------------
 0   0x0001       1   TC0H  CPU Heatsink
 1   0x0002       2   TG0H  GPU Heatsink
 2   0x0004       4   TH0P  HDD Proximity
 3   0x0008       8   TO0P  ODD Proximity
 4   0x0010      16   Tm0P  MLB Proximity
 5   0x0020      32   TA0P  Ambient
 6   0x0040      64   Tp0P  Power Supply Proximity
 7   0x0080     128   TW0P  Wireless (Airport) Proximity
 8   0x0100     256   TC0P  CPU Proximity
 9   0x0200     512   TC0D  CPU Die
10   0x0400    1024   TG0P  GPU Proximity
11   0x0800    2048   TG0D  GPU Die
12   0x1000    4096   TL0P  LCD Proximity
13   0x2000    8192   SGTT  GPU Heatsink Throttle Threshold
```